# Filtering through data in a column based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I need to do the two following things:

1) Delete all rows whereby Current Entity Name equals
Subscription Line of Credit
Other Assets
Net Other Assets
Liabilities
Cash and Cash Equivalents.

2)Append “#UP#” to all of the remaining records of Current Entity Name.
(i.e if Current Entity Name = St Georges Hospital, after running macro, it should end up as #UP#St Georges Hospital).

Current Entity is in column D.

I have the following codes:

```
Sub Test()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim CurrentEntityColumn As Integer
Dim POColumn As Integer
Dim DomColumn As Integer
Dim i As Long



 MsgBox ("Select Investment Analysis_Before")
Sourcefile = Application.GetOpenFilename()
Workbooks.Open (Sourcefile)



CurrentEntityColumn = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To CurrentEntityColumn
If Cells(i, "D").Value = "Subscription Line of Credit" Or Cells(i, "D").Value = "Other Assets" Then
Cells(i, "D").EntireRow.Delete
End If


Next i
End Sub
```

However, the code dont seem to be working as it only deletes whatever that I put last in the or argument. In this case it only deletes rows which column D contains "Other Assets". Subscription Line of Credit is not deleted.

I also observed that this error only occurs when I use entirerow.delete. I have tried using changing the font color if cell contains "Subscription Line of Credit" and it works fine.

Can anyone tell me what have I done wrongly and also any ideas to complete task 2? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

what about:

```
If Cells(i, "D").Value = "Subscription Line of Credit" Then
  Cells(i, "D").EntireRow.Delete
ElseIf Cells(i, "D").Value = "Other Assets" Then
  Cells(i, "D").EntireRow.Delete
Else
  Cells(i, "D").Value = "#UP#" & Cells(i, "D").Value
End If
```